# Can I install ubuntu without windows mac or linux and using a hard disk drive?

Tags: kernel

So my laptop has died. The hard disk was making a weird sound so I bought a new hard disk. Both, old and new hard disk showed me the same error that no operating system was found. I am quite desperate to find a way to check if other parts are spoilt without sending it to service. And one my friends suggested downloading a Linux system to test it out. So can I install Ubuntu without windows, mac or any os, and using a hard disk drive. My laptop is currently only capable of accessing bios. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
My laptop was an Acer Aspire series if that helps!

Comment: Since you were able to post the question, you obviously have access to another computer.  Have you reviewed the installation instructions found here => [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation]

Comment: With your new hard disk drive, of course, there isn't any OS installed in it. It's a brand new hard disk by the way. It's fresh and empty drive. You can install any OS on it. Whether its Linux, or any other OS.

Comment: sometimes the acer aspire series has a weird problem with the screen during installation, if you have trouble, just post another question as there are solutions if you run into any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Does the error message say something along the lines of "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"? If so, try flipping your laptop over and popping the battery out for a few minutes, then put it back in and turn it on. I get that error from time to time and that seems to fix it.

But to actually answer your question, yes you should be able to. So long as your computer supports booting from a cd or USB, and you've properly formatted it ([if you don't know how, you'd need to borrow a friends computer to do this though](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)). Just stick it in, open your BIOS, and prioritize CD or USB, whatever you're using, above everything else.